# How to send data to php server using AFNetworking in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I have some data like (Image & Text). I want to send this data to PHP server using AFNetworking through my objective c coding.

My Response is like this:

[image]

I have to send designation & about field text to PHP server.

My code is like below:

```
   - (void) upload 
   {
      AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
      manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

      NSDictionary *params = @ {@"about" :self.aboutField.text, @"designation" :self.desinationField.text };

      [manager POST:@UPDATE_PROFILE_URL parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
      {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
      }
         failure:
      ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
   }
```

And I am adding "text/html" to `acceptableContentTypes` set in `AFURLResponseSerialization` class.

When I run my app I got below error:

```
 Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7d405870 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Please Help me out.

Comment: You set request serializer to JSON , but I think you talk about responseSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12 Tutorial covers uploading images to server using afnetworing and php

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to upload image & text on Server using `AFNetworking`.

Add these 2 class **AFNetworking** & **UIKit+AFNetworking**

Import :

```
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
```

This is my Code :

```
 - (void)uploadProfile_Details
{
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@UPDATE_PROFILE_URL]];

   // Retrieve Image from Document directory------

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"profileImg.png"];
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];

   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);

   // Create dictionary for sending text to server ------

   NSDictionary *parameters  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.desinationField.text,@"designation",self.teamField.text,@"team",self.aboutField.text,@"about",self.skillLbl.text,@"skills",self.interestField.text,@"interests", nil];
   AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:@UPDATE_PROFILE_URL parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
   {
       //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
       [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"myimage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
   } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)     {
     NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
 }];
 [operation start];
}
```